# How to add string at specific index only whenever a button is clicked?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have initialized this in my reducer:

```
const valueInitialState = {
   list: {
     breadcrumb: [],
   }
}
```

When this **handleClick** is called, it will only replace the value at the first index of the array. Example, if title is "FirstText", then breadcrumb will be: ["FirstText"]. If the **handleClick** function is called again with a different title, example, "SecondText", it will replace the first title to be ["SecondText"]. I tried using splice, it did not work.

```
    const handleClick = (title) => {

        dispatch(
            someFunction({
                list: {
                    breadcrumb: [breadcrumb.splice(0,1,title)]
                },
            })
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should clone `breadcrumb` list

And then replace a value with a particular index directly like below

```
const handleClick = (title, replacingIndex) => {
        const updatedBreadcrumb = [...breadcrumb] //clone an array

        updatedBreadcrumb[replacingIndex] = title //set title to a particular item in an array

        dispatch(
            someFunction({
                list: {
                    breadcrumb: updatedBreadcrumb
                },
            })
        );
    };
```

Side note, if you don't want to have `replacingIndex` param as a dynamic index value, you can pass the index like below

```
updatedBreadcrumb[0] = title //0 is your expected index
```